# replace item in array to avoid redundancy

Tags: javascript, lodash

It's ok to use lodash to simplfly stuff, just curious how can I do this case:

I want to do a filter, it's list of checkbox, so in the state I want to have something like

```
['apple','samsung'];
```

I can do manual push and delete but I'm looking for lodash method to make cleaner code.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? What is the input ? The output ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to delete duplicates using the `Array.prototype.filter` method (Documentation is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)) . You can do something like this:

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,4];
arr.filter((e1, e2) => e1 !== e2); // will return [1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#uniqBy)

`_.uniqBy(array, [iteratee=_.identity])` .

_.uniqBy([2.1, 1.2, 2.1] ); will return [2.1, 1.2]